# Can I claim exempt on my taxes if I invest what I would pay in tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, irs

I recently overheard in conversation that I might have the ability to evade Uncle Sam touching my money if I invested what I would pay in taxes for the year into a IRA or ROTH account? Is this true?

Comment: Are you asking whether investing your money means you won't owe taxes?  That is definitely false.

Comment: I was under the impression that you received tax credit for opening investment accounts? That's why I inquired. Not eliminate my taxes completely...though that might be ideal. But reduce them.

Comment: See my answer.  You don't get a tax credit for "opening" accounts.  You can potentially get a *deduction* (and/or a small credit) for contributing money to retirement accounts.  Your question is fairly vague about exactly how you think this works.  If you have a reference to a source for your information, that would help in responding.

Comment: This is probably a technicality that you did not intend, but tax *evasion* is a crime.  Tax *avoidance* is legal.  See the answers about how much you can avoid.  I don't think you'll get any answers here about evasion, which is what you literally asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is definitely not true that you can exempt yourself from all taxes just by investing your money.  If you owe taxes, you owe them; you can't just invest the money "instead".

That said, there are two things that may be relevant to your question.  First, if you put money into a traditional IRA, you may (depending on your income) be able to deduct some or all of that contribution from your taxable income.  This means that your taxes will be reduced.  (However, you will pay taxes on the money when you withdraw it, presumably after you retire.)  Read the details at [the IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/IRA-Deduction-Limits).

Second, if you put money into either a Traditional or Roth IRA, you may (depending on your income) be eligible for the ["Saver's Credit"](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc610.html), which will also reduce your taxes.

The amount you can contribute to IRAs (traditional and Roth) is limited, so these maneuvers will likely only reduce your tax by a relatively small amount.  There is no secret mechanism that will allow you to escape taxes.

Comment: +1... one small thing: s/your taxes will be reduced/your taxes will be *deferred* /